# jQuery AJAX JSON quotations format to WCF

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

Here's my sample code:

```
var postData = '{"studentId":"' + $("#hidId").val() + '"}';
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'SomeService.svc/AddId',
   data: postData,
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function (msg) {
      //do something...
   }
});
```

I wanted the quotation of postData to be as it(with double quotes surrounding the parameter, single code does not work for me), but when browser runs it, all the single quote become double quotes, and double quotes remained as it, and it become something like this:

`"{"studentId":"ST001"}"`

I need the string in this format:

`'{"studentId":"ST001"}'`

Anyone know how to overcome this problem?

UPDATE: 
Sorted it out myself, problem lies with the data value I submitted back, the 'studentId' should be Guid in order to be matched with WCF service parameter type.

Answer (score 1):

Use the escape character \

```
var postData = '{"studentId":\'' + $("#hidId").val() + '\'}';
```

Comment: Could you please write which result you are after? eg: '{"studentId":"ST001"}' or {"studentId":ST001} or {"studentId":"ST001"} or {"studentId":'ST001'}?

Comment: {"studentId":"ST001"} <-- This is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
var postData = {};
postData.studentId = $("#hidId").val();
```

...

```
data: JSON.stringify(postData),
```

Comment: After stringify it, the result become this:
`""{\"StudentId\":\"ST001\"}""`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that postData needs to be a javascript object.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Doesn't help, it still give me this: `"{"StudentId":"ST001"}"`